# C producer/consumer - outputting same data and getting stuck before finishing

Tags: c, operating-system, semaphore, producer-consumer

We have an assignment based on the producer/consumer problem. Essentially, the assignment boils down to this:

- Let `N_PROD, N_CON` represent the number of producer/consumer threads respectively that are created, and let `BUF_SIZE` represent size of buffer.
- Each producer thread has to select 2 random prime numbers, multiply them, and add the result to a buffer
- Let`TOTAL_PRIMES` represent how many times *in total* elements are added or removed from buffer. Obviously some threads may access buffer more than others (e.g., if `TOTAL_PRIMES=5` and `N_PROD=3`, then it's perfectly fine if `producer1` adds  three different products to buffer, `producer2` adds two, and `producer3` adds none).
- The spawned threads should only begin working after the main thread has created *all* producers/consumers.

Each time I execute the program though, it never seems to surpass 3 or 4 prime products. Further, it seems to keep writing the same data.

My main question is why doesn't the program ever reach the end? I can't seem to figure out where it's getting stuck. I don't know if the repeated data is a consequence of the first problem, or if they're two separate issues.

Here is what I think is the most relevant part of my code (so not including any functions that simply do some calculations or output something to console):

```
// Declaration of thread condition variable 
pthread_cond_t start_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; 
// declaring mutex 
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; 

lluint buf[BUF_SIZE];

int p_count = 0;
int c_count = 0;
int all_started = 0;
int pdone = 0;
int cdone = 0;

//////////////////////////////////
sem_t* sem_access;
sem_t* sem_occupy;  //how many elements currently in buffer
sem_t* sem_free;    //how much free space we have
sem_t* sem_all_started;

sem_t* sem_buf;

///////////////////////////////////////////

// int main()
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    close_Semaphors();

    pthread_t p_threads[N_PROD];
    pthread_t c_threads[N_CONS];

    open_all_sem(); //helper function to opens all semaphores listed above

    int rc, t;
    for (t=0; t<N_PROD; t++)
    {
        rc = pthread_create(&p_threads[t], NULL, producer, (void*)t);
        if (rc)
        {
          printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
          exit(-1);
       }
    }


    sem_wait(sem_access);   
    printf("main thread created all producer threads\n");   
    sem_post(sem_access);   

    for (t=0; t<N_CONS; t++)
    { 
        rc = pthread_create(&c_threads[t], NULL, consumer, (void*)t);
        if (rc)
        {
          printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
          exit(-1);
       }
    }

    printf("main thread created all consumer threads\n");   
    broadcast_all_started();

    for (t=0; t<N_PROD; t++)
    {
        rc = pthread_join(p_threads[t], NULL);
        if (rc != 0)
        {
            printf("Error joining producer thread %d\n", t+1);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    for (t=0; t<N_CONS; t++)
    {
        rc = pthread_join(c_threads[t], NULL);
        if (rc != 0)
        {
            printf("Error joining consumer thread %d\n", t+1);
            exit(-1);
        }

    }

    printf("Back in main thread\n");

    sem_unlink("/sem_free");
    sem_unlink("/sem_access"); 
    sem_unlink("/sem_occupy");
    sem_unlink("/sem_all_started");
    sem_unlink("/sem_buf");

    printf("Goodbye!\n");
    close_Semaphors();
    return 0;
}



void producer(void* id)
{
    wait_in_threads_until_all_start();
    int p_id = (int)id + 1;

    while (!pdone)
    {
        lluint prime1, prime2, primeProd;

        prime1 = getPrimeNum();  
        prime2 = getPrimeNum();
        primeProd = prime1 * prime2;


        sem_wait(sem_free); 
        sem_wait(sem_access);   
        write_add_to_buf_msg(p_id, prime1, prime2, primeProd);   
        write_producer_is_done(p_id);  //simply outputs something 
        sem_post(sem_access);
        sem_post(sem_occupy);   

        p_count++;
        if (p_count == TOTAL_MSG)
        {
            printf("all producers terminated\n");
            pdone = 1;
        }
    }

    if (pdone == 1)
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void add_to_buf (lluint prod)
{

    sem_wait(sem_buf);
    int val;
    sem_getvalue(sem_occupy, &val);

    buf[val] = prod;
    sem_post(sem_buf);      
}


void consumer(void* id)
{
    wait_in_threads_until_all_start();
    int c_id = (int)id+1;

    while (!cdone)
    {       
        sem_wait(sem_occupy);

        lluint prod, factor1, factor2;      
        sem_wait(sem_access);   
        write_remove_from_buf_msg(c_id, &prod); //within this we call remove_from_buf
        find_two_factors(prod, &factor1, &factor2);     
        printf(" = %lli x %lli\n", factor1, factor2);
        write_consumer_is_done(c_id);
        sem_post(sem_access);   
        sem_post(sem_free);
        c_count++;  

        if (c_count == TOTAL_MSG)
        {
            printf("all consumers terminated\n");
            cdone = 1;
        }
    }
    if (cdone == 1)
        pthread_exit(NULL);

}


void remove_from_buf(lluint* prod)
{
    sem_wait(sem_buf);   

    int val;
    sem_getvalue(sem_occupy, &val);

    *prod = buf[val];
    sem_post(sem_buf);   
}


void wait_in_threads_until_all_start()
{
    sem_post(sem_all_started);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    if (all_started == 0)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&start_cond, &lock); 
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}


void all_threads_ready()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    all_started = 1;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&start_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}



void close_Semaphors(void)
{
    sem_close(sem_access);
    sem_close(sem_occupy);
    sem_close(sem_free);
    sem_close(sem_all_started);
    sem_close(sem_buf);
}
```

Here is the output from 4 separate runs of the program (each time I had to enter ``cntl+c``` to stop it)

Output1.txt

```
main thread created all producer threads
main thread created all consumer threads
producer #1 going to add product: 15347 = 103 x 149
producer #1 is done
producer #2 going to add product: 15347 = 103 x 149
producer #2 is done
consumer #3 just removed: 15347 = 103 x 149
consumer #3 is done
consumer #1 just removed: 15347 = 103 x 149
consumer #1 is done
producer #1 going to add product: 19367 = 107 x 181
producer #1
```

Output2.txt

```
main thread created all producer threads
main thread created all consumer threads
producer #1 going to add product: 15347 = 103 x 149
producer #1
```

Output3.txt

```
main thread created all producer threads
main thread created all consumer threads
producer #1 going to add product: 15347 = 103 x 149
producer #1 is done
consumer #3 just removed: 15347 = 103 x 149
consumer #3 is done
producer #1 going to add product: 19367 = 107 x 181
producer #1 is done
consumer #2 just removed: 19367 = 107 x 181
consumer #2 is done
producer #1 going to add product: 27221 = 163 x 167
producer #1 is done
consumer #1 just removed: 27221 = 163 x 167
consumer #1
```

Output4.txt

```
main thread created all producer threads
main thread created all consumer threads
producer #1 going to add product: 15347 = 103 x 149
producer #1 is done
consumer #3 just removed: 15347 = 103 x 149
consumer #3 is done
producer #1 going to add product: 19367 = 107 x 181
producer #1 is done
consumer #1 just removed: 19367 = 107 x 181
consumer #1 is done
producer #1 going to add product: 27221 = 163 x 167
producer #1 is done
consumer #2 just removed: 27221 = 163 x 167
consumer #2 is done
producer #1 going to add product: 20651 = 107 x 193
producer #1 is done
consumer #3 just removed: 20651 = 107 x 193
consumer #3 is done
producer #1 going to add product: 30967 = 173 x 179
producer #1 is done
consumer #1 just removed: 30967 = 173 x 179
consumer #1
```

Comment: p_count and c_count are simple global variables and are not protected from race conditions. Both counters should be handled in a thread-safe manner. The variables pdone and cdone are unnecessary. The producer and consumer threads can be exited where these ints are assigned the value 1. The thread loops should be infinite loops that execute until pthread_exit() is called.

Comment: Remember that the Total_Primes includes the number of times a buffer element was written to the buffer plus the number of times a buffer element was read from the buffer. The consumers must wait for one or more producers to populate the buffer before the elements can be consumed. This means that the producers should produce more elements than the consumers consume.